# Squeryl get value of serial

Tags: auto-increment, atomic, squeryl

I insert a new row into a database and its id is auto-incremented ("serial"). How can I get the value of the id after insertion? Currently, I am using the following workaround:

```
inTransaction {
  Schema.table.insert(new Entry(
      content = "..."
  ))
  def entries = from(Schema.table)(e => select(e) orderBy(e.id desc)).page(0, 1)
  val id = entries.headOption match {
    case Some(entry) => entry.id
    case None => 0
  }
}
```

If there is no easier way, how can I ensure this entire block will be an atomic operation?

Answer (score 0):

yes,

```
val new = Schema.table.insert(myOriginalOld)
Console println new.id
```

Comment: How would this work, `myOriginalOld` does not have the `id` member and `new` must be of the same type as `myOriginalOld`. If `myOriginalOld` was provided with `id`, I would have to use `on(entries)(entry => declare(entry.id is(autoIncremented("Entry_id_seq"))))` which causes an `ExceptionInInitializerError` on my machine. Otherwise it would not work either...

Comment: You can use KeyedEntity. For example, if you want the simplest Primary Key in your database, use smth like
`case class Fuit(id: Long = 0L, color: String) extends KeyedEntity[Long]`
In your question you said that you want the id from the database. If so, the squeryl object MUST contain the id.